# Add an icon to (custom right_click menu) , Application.ShortcutMenus

Tags: excel, vba, icons

I am using this code to add an entry to excel right_click menu:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.Add "Open document", "OpenDocument", , 1, , ""
End Sub

Sub OpenDocument()
‘vba code here
End Sub
```

I need to add an icon to this entry (using shell32.dl or any standalone image), as it is now blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be solved in more ways, but (at least, this is what I know how to handle) using a different approach (`CommandBar`):

1. To place a custom picture, please try the first version. It uses a picture from a specific path:

```
Sub AddItemContextMenuWithImage_1()
      Const butName As String = "Open document"
      Const calledProc As String = "testSubX"
      
      deleteCellCustomControl butName
      
      Dim cmBar As CommandBar, ctrlButt As CommandBarButton, picPicture As IPictureDisp
      
      Set cmBar = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
      Set ctrlButt = cmBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1) 'create it to be the first menu option
      Set picPicture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.gif") 'accepted extensions: bmp, jpg, gif
      
      With ctrlButt
        .Picture = picPicture
        .OnAction = calledProc
        .Caption = butName
    End With
End Sub
```

To check it, the demonstative `Sub` should look as:

```
Sub testSubX()
  MsgBox "It works..."
End Sub
```

Of course, you may adapt the code to call your own/necessary `Sub`...

2. A second version uses/copies a picture already added on a specific sheet of `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub AddItemContextMenuWithImage_2()
      Const butName As String = "Open document"
      Const calledProc As String = "testSubX"
      
      deleteCellCustomControl butName
      
      Dim cmBar As CommandBar, ctrlButt As CommandBarButton
      
      Set cmBar = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
      Set ctrlButt = cmBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1) 'create it to be the first menu option
      ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 2").Copy 'need to have a "Picture 2" picture on the active sheet
                                                                            'you can copy it as image of the newly added control button
      With ctrlButt
       .PasteFace 'paste the above copied picture
        .OnAction = calledProc
        .Caption = butName
    End With
End Sub
```

3. The third version uses standard, already defined `FaceIDs`. There are so many, that it is very probable to find something suitable for your need, so this is the version I prefer:

```
Sub AddItemContextMenuWithImage_3()
      'Here the list of FaceID controls with their images:
      'https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/face-ids-2003.htm
      Const butName As String = "Open document"
      Const calledProc As String = "testSubX"
      
      deleteCellCustomControl butName
      
      Dim cmBar As CommandBar, ctrlButt As CommandBarButton
      
      Set cmBar = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
      Set ctrlButt = cmBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1) 'create it to be the first menu option
      
      With ctrlButt
        .FaceId = 1661
        .OnAction = calledProc
        .Caption = butName
    End With
End Sub
```

A lot of such `FaceIDs` can be found [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/face-ids-2003.htm). I also place the link as a comment inside the `Sub`, to remain there for people being interested in this approach...

All the above Subs firstly call the next `Sub`, to preliminarily delete the menu option, if it already exists:

```
Sub deleteCellCustomControl(strBut As String)
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case of not existing button to be deleted...
     Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems(strBut).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

If there is only such a custom option in the context menu, or if you want deleting all of them (the custom once), you can simple reset the command Bar, using:

```
Private Sub ResetContextMenuBar()
   Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
End Sub
```

Comment: All Works perfectly as  expected . For me, It is the first time to know `FaceId` terminology.

Comment: @Waleed I edited the question and also added a `Sub` able to reset the bar. I tried explaining when it's good to be used... I use this way from Office 2003 period. If I remember well, you can even delete the standard options (as `Cut`, `Copy`, `Insert...` etc.).